# Pasar variable de un evento a global javascript

Tags: javascript, array, eventos

Hola buenas deseo pasar una variable de un evento a una variable global, pero no me da resultado, como puedo hacerlo de la manera correcta?

```
var producto = [];
console.log("El producto seleccionado fue", producto);    // esto me retorna undefined
$(".btnAgregar").on("click", function () {
    producto = $(this).data("collection");
});
```

Quiero que el elemento "collection" pase a la variable producto que está fuera de el evento

De que manera puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Hola Daglas, si estas usando ese código tal cual lo muestras ahi el console.log no deberia de darte undefined ya que la linea anterior esta declarado como array. Segundo cuando asignas a producto el dato de $(this).data("collection"), en que parte del codigo le asignaste el data?

Answer (score 0):

```
var producto = [];
console.log("El producto seleccionado fue", producto);    // esto me retorna undefined
$(".btnAgregar").on("click", function () {
    producto = $(this).data("collection");
});
```

Al ejecutarse este código pasa lo siguiente:

- Se crea una variable array sin asignación.
- Se imprimen los elementos del array. (No hay).
- Se añade el evento.

Cuando compruebas el array aún está vacio.
Tienes que meter el console.log dentro de la función que se llamará al detectarse el evento:

```
var producto = [];

$(".btnAgregar").on("click", function () {
  producto = $(this).data("collection");
  console.log("El producto seleccionado fue", producto); 
});
```